# How to use custom CultureInfo in NUnit?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, cultureinfo

I want tests to use custom `CultureInfo`.

I created my `CultureInfo` and set this to `TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentCulture` property. But it doesn't work. Tests are still using default culture.

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
public async Task OneTimeSetUp() {
    var culture = new CultureInfo( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name );
    culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss:fff";
    TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentCulture = culture;

    await Task.Delay( 1 );
}

[Test]
public void Test() {
    TestContext.WriteLine( TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentCulture.EnglishName ); // Russian (Ukraine)
    TestContext.WriteLine( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.EnglishName ); // Russian (Ukraine)
    TestContext.WriteLine( Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.EnglishName );
}
```

How can I do it?

**Update:** It doesn't work only for async `OneTimeSetUp` methods.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: `DateTime.ToString()` doesn't use my `LongTimePattern`.

Comment: Does it work if you run this code in your actual test, rather than the OneTimeSetUp?

Comment: Yes, it works in test method.

Comment: As a slight hack, try adding `[SingleThreaded]` to your test class.

Comment: `SingleThreaded` didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can set up `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` only in not `async` `OneTimeSetUp` methods.